# vertical scroll in viewpager jetpack compose is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

Facing issue with a vertical scroll in Horizontal View Pager using Accompanist. Can't scroll the column
vertically inside HorizontalViewPager. So take a look at code and make corrections on how can fix it or any other solution. If possible will be appreciated.

```
                HorizontalPager(
                count = 10,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) { page ->



                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .fillMaxHeight(),
                ){
                    ScoreCardListItem()
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    ScoreCardListItem()
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    ScoreCardListItem()
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    ScoreCardListItem()
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    ScoreCardListItem()
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    ScoreCardListItem()
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    ScoreCardListItem()
                }
            }
```

can't scroll vertically while using Column. If Try to use LazyColumn It produces an error. Here is Accompanist ViewPager Link
[Accompanist Library](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/)

Answer (score 1):

check using LazyColumn

```
           LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .fillMaxSize()
             ) {
                 item {
                    ScoreCardListItem()
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    ScoreCardListItem()
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    ScoreCardListItem()
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    ScoreCardListItem()
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    ScoreCardListItem()
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    ScoreCardListItem()
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    ScoreCardListItem()
                   }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Actually, I was using Column inside Composable function. That's why It was generating error, removed Colum, and place in item{}. Then it worked. The solution is LazyColumn.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use the vertical scroll property of the Modifier. Like in the below code

```
modifier = Modifier
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
```